# flagging redundant rows with NA

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with complete and incomplete rows, something like :

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "one" = c(1, 1, 1, 3, NA),
  "two" = c(2, 2, NA, 4, 4),
  "three" = c(1, 1, NA, 5, 5),
  "four"  = c(2, NA, 2, 6, 6)
)
```

I want to tag the rows that contain NA's as TRUE where their values equal values in the same column, on a row with fewer NA's, so

```
dat$redundant <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Essentially I'm looking for `duplicated(dat, MARGIN = 1)` but with `NA` counting as a match to any present values. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you get the last row TRUE

Comment: This would be clearer if your example `dat` had a row that included an NA but desired value of `redundant` is FALSE, because there is a unique value in one of the columns of that row. I think `dat <- data.frame(
  "one" = c(1, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA),
  "two" = c(2, 2, NA, 4, 4, 9),
  "three" = c(1, 1, NA, 5, 5, 5),
  "four"  = c(2, NA, 2, 6, 6,6)
)`
..might do this?

Comment: The example can give expected output with different ways.  It is better if the example can be made a bit unique

Comment: You're right @PeterEllis, your example is better - the final row in your data.frame should return `FALSE`.

Comment: @akrun if the final row had a 3 where the NA is, it would match the row above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, wound up using a grep-based approach instead, which I guess is a bit weird but works:

```
  find_unique_combos <- function(dat) {

    na_count <- rowSums(is.na(dat))

    strings <- apply(dat, MARGIN = 1, function(row) {
      row[is.na(row)] <- '.'
      paste0(row, collapse ='')
    })
    
    sapply(seq_along(strings), function(i) {
      if(na_count[i] == 0) { return(TRUE) }
      test_targets <- strings[na_count <= na_count[i]]
      test_targets <- test_targets[!test_targets %in% strings[i]]
      !any(grepl(strings[i], test_targets))
    })

  }
```

There are no duplicate rows in my input datasets and they're not very big tables, so this should be problem-free. Thanks for getting me thinking, all.

Answer (score 5):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
     fill(everything()) %>% 
     duplicated
 #[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This gets pretty close, but its somewhat dependent on the sorting order of the rows. Sometimes `fill()` places a value that returns an incorrect result.

Comment: @obrl_soil So, how do you want the NA to be filled up

Comment: I'm not actually sure this is the right approach at all - what I'm aiming for is almost a partial grep, e.g. concatenating the row values to a string, '12.45' should be redundant against '12345'. Each row would need to be compared to any other row with fewer NAs. Seems like this would get inefficient quickly...

Comment: @obrl_soil ok, you got other solutions as well.  Please check those if it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can `sweep` the difference per row, build the `rowSums` ignoring `NA`, ignor the upper tri and diag. From this where the `rowSums` are `>0` should indicate the duplicated rows ignoring `NA`.

```
tt <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
 function(i) rowSums(sweep(dat, 2, unlist(dat[i,])), TRUE)==0)
tt[upper.tri(tt, TRUE)] <- FALSE
rowSums(tt) > 0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Adding line 2 to `dat` and try it again:

```
dat2 <- rbind(dat, dat[2,])
tt <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat2)),
 function(i) rowSums(sweep(dat2, 2, unlist(dat2[i,])), TRUE)==0)
tt[upper.tri(tt, TRUE)] <- FALSE
dat2$redundant <- rowSums(tt) > 0
dat2
#   one two three four redundant
#1    1   2     1    2     FALSE
#2    1   2     1   NA      TRUE
#3    1  NA    NA    2      TRUE
#4    3   4     5    6     FALSE
#5   NA   4     5    6      TRUE
#21   1   2     1   NA      TRUE
```

And with the data from @Peter-Ellis (Thanks!):

```
dat <- data.frame("one" = c(1, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA), "two" = c(2, 2, NA, 4, 4, 9),   
  "three" = c(1, 1, NA, 5, 5, 5), "four"  = c(2, NA, 2, 6, 6,6) )
tt <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
 function(i) rowSums(sweep(dat, 2, unlist(dat[i,])), TRUE)==0)
tt[upper.tri(tt, TRUE)] <- FALSE
rowSums(tt) > 0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This won't work in the situation where there is an NA in one column but the other columns in that row are not duplicates of the rest of their columns (if I understand the "where their values equal values int eh same column, on a row with fewer NASs" part of the OP).

Comment: @PeterEllis Thanks for the clarification! Hope the update works now as expected.

Comment: Maybe try your solution on `dat <- data.frame(
  "one" = c(1, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA),
  "two" = c(2, 2, NA, 4, 4, 9),
  "three" = c(1, 1, NA, 5, 5, 5),
  "four"  = c(2, NA, 2, 6, 6,6)
)
` which should return FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE

Comment: hmm this one only seems to be setting FALSE on complete cases, unfortunately

Comment: @obrl_soil So you want that the comparison with `NA` works only in one direction? Like `1 == NA` but `NA != 1`?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this seems to me really tricky and I may have misunderstood the question. Here is at least the beginning of an answer. As per my comments, here is an extended version of your original example

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "one" = c(1, 1, 1, 3, NA, NA),
  "two" = c(2, 2, NA, 4, 4, 9),
  "three" = c(1, 1, NA, 5, 5, 5),
  "four"  = c(2, NA, 2, 6, 6,6)
)

# desired behaviour is foo(dat) = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

For the record, this is what `dat` looks like:

```
> dat
  one two three four
1   1   2     1    2
2   1   2     1   NA
3   1  NA    NA    2
4   3   4     5    6
5  NA   4     5    6
6  NA   9     5    6
```

Desired behaviour is `TRUE` when a row both contains an NA, AND does not contain in any of its columns a value that is unique for that column (unique that is for the columns that are in the data after we remove the other rows that are going to be flagged TRUE - an important proviso I might be misinterpreting from your question).

Here is a very clunky solution. It involves going through the data one cell at a time! Very un-R like.

```
foo <- function(d){
  # we are going to approach this backwards! You are a "good" row if you 
  # are either complete, or one of your cells is unique in its column, compared
  # to the good rows
  
  
  flag1 <- complete.cases(d)
  
  flag2 <- rep(FALSE, nrow(d))
  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(d)){
      # check if the value in this row, col is NOT IN any of the complete cases
      # of data in other rows or rows that we are keeping
      if(!is.na(d[i, j]) && !d[i, j] %in% d[-i, j][flag1 | flag2]){
        flag2[i] <- TRUE
      }
    }
  }
  
  # so flag3 is EITHER your row is complete, OR it has a unique value
  flag3 <- (flag1 | flag2)
  
  # now we return the not-good rows, so TRUE will be redundant rows
  return(!flag3)

}
```

It works with the original test case:

```
> foo(dat)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

However, I can think of problematic edge cases. What if the last row of our data was repeated? I'm not sure what the desired behaviour here is, but I am giving a FALSE to the first time you get a 9 in column two, then TRUE later (as these are duplicates of previous rows). See:

```
> dat2 <- rbind(dat, c(NA, 9, 5, 6))
> dat2
  one two three four
1   1   2     1    2
2   1   2     1   NA
3   1  NA    NA    2
4   3   4     5    6
5  NA   4     5    6
6  NA   9     5    6
7  NA   9     5    6
> foo(dat2)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

So you might need to edit this depending on what your actual desired behaviour is in this and related edge cases. But hopefully this has given you a start.

Comment: I think @akrun's solution is much better than mine but I'm leaving this here for posterity. I just didn't think of filling in the NAs and then identifying duplicates from there.

Comment: I see where you're going with this and I think you might be correct, but your function throws an indexing error on my real data. `Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 1 but subscript `flag1 | flag2` has size 61.`
switching to || didn't help

Comment: I think you need a more complete demo data set and comprehensive description of the actual algorithm because I think there are several ambiguities as described.